# I want to create a loop for my SQL query using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

The below Query is running successfully for single row, I want to repeat the same until 'A' row is empty.Basically, i am copying from A2 and executing that, Results will be loaded into B2.Then Creating one text file store the 'Query n results' and creating a hyperlink.

Kindly help me create a loop and do this until 'A' Columns is empty

This is my Query:

```
'First Query
Set Sql = Sheet1.Range("A2")
Set Rec_set = cn.Execute(Sql) 'Issue SQL statement
While Not Rec_set.EOF
Sheet1.Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset Rec_set
Wend
Rec_set.Close 'Close the recordset

'Write into TEXT file
Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Text\Row2.txt", True, True)
Fileout.Write Sheet1.Range("A2")
Fileout.Write vbNewLine
Fileout.Write vbNewLine
Fileout.Write "COUNT"
Fileout.Write vbNewLine
Fileout.Write "*****"
Fileout.Write vbNewLine
Fileout.Write Sheet1.Range("B2")
Fileout.Close
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("C2").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
        Address:="https:XXXXXXXXXXXXX/Screenshots/Text/Row2.txt", _
        ScreenTip:="Hyperlink", _
        TextToDisplay:="Row2"
End With
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following should work as expected:

```
Sub foo()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'First Query
For i = 2 To LastRow
    Set Sql = Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
    Set Rec_set = cn.Execute(Sql) 'Issue SQL statement
    While Not Rec_set.EOF
    Sheet1.Range("B" & i).CopyFromRecordset Rec_set
    Wend
    Rec_set.Close 'Close the recordset

    NewPath = "C:\Text\Row" & i & ".txt"
    'Write into TEXT file
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(NewPath, True, True)
    Fileout.Write Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
    Fileout.Write vbNewLine
    Fileout.Write vbNewLine
    Fileout.Write "COUNT"
    Fileout.Write vbNewLine
    Fileout.Write "*****"
    Fileout.Write vbNewLine
    Fileout.Write Sheet1.Range("B" & i)
    Fileout.Close
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("C" & i).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
            Address:="https:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Screenshots/Text/Row" & i & ".txt", _
            ScreenTip:="Hyperlink", _
            TextToDisplay:="Row" & i
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,its working perfectly :):) Kudossssss Thankssss

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop from the first row of A to the last row of A. Thus, on an empty worksheet, write a few words in column `A` and try this part separately. Then adjust it to your code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim lastRowA As Long
    Dim cnt As Long

    lastRowA = lastRow

    For cnt = 1 To lastRowA
        Debug.Print Cells(cnt, 1)
    Next cnt

End Sub

Function lastRow(Optional wsName As String, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If wsName = vbNullString Then
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
    End If

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

The `lastRow` function has 2 optional parameters - thus, if you need the last row of column `B` of `Sheets2` then it would look like this -> `lastRow("Sheet1",2)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Its not working as expected.Can you please edit in my code and send it back.Thanks in advance